# Difference between jQuery date picker and bootstrap date picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, model-view-controller, datepicker

I am searching many blogs but I didn't clarity, which version of jQuery and bootstrap to use. In my code, I am facing error like datepicker is not a function. I am not clear what is missing here actually.

I have mentioned, index.cshtml, layout and bundle config code blocks. Also it will be greatly helpful, if anyone provide me the tutorials that could differentiate the jQuery and bootstrap widgets.

1. what exactly do I need to add in head section
2. render scripts?

Code:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>          
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script  type="text/javascript">    
     $(document).ready(function () {
       $( '#datepicker' ).datepicker();
     });
  </script>
</head>
<body>     
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" /></p>      
</body>
</html> 
layout.cshtml:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>       
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.24.min.js"></script>       
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>  <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    @RenderBody()       
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>   
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Optimization;
namespace DatePickerTest
{
    public class BundleConfig
    {
        // For more information on Bundling, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=254725
        public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));    
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));    
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));    
            // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
            // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include("~/Content/site.css"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/themes/base/css").Include(
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.core.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.resizable.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.selectable.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.accordion.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.autocomplete.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.button.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.dialog.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.slider.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.tabs.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.datepicker.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.progressbar.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Datepicker is available in jQuery-ui not in jQuery core.
https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: Please don't post your entire server-side Razor view when you actually ask a client-side question. What technology you use on the server is irrelevant to your question, cut out everything you are not asking about and post HTML and Javascript as the browser sees it.